# Suppressing warnings about an unused Kotlin property in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, code-inspection, intellij-inspections

Consider I have a parameterized *TestNG* test:

```
val parameters: Array<Array<Any>>
    @DataProvider
    get() {
        val parameters = arrayListOf<Array<Any>>()
        // ...
        return parameters.toTypedArray()
    }

@Test(dataProvider = "getParameters")
fun test(p1: Any, pN: Any) {
    // ...
}
```

How do I stop *IDEA* from complaining that the data provider property (`parameters` in our case) is unused? Annotating the property with `@get:SuppressWarnings("unused")` is not helpful.

Comment: Have you tried to add the `DataProvider` annotation in File | Settings | Editor | Inspections Kotlin | Redundant constructs | Unused symbol -> | **Annotations...**?

Comment: @Andrey Thanks for the hint, but no, this didn't help. I've found a workaround though -- see my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53171928/1343979).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There turned out to be a workaround. Rewriting the annotation like this:

```
@get:DataProvider
val parameters: Array<Array<Any>>
```

makes *IDEA* treat the property as an entry point.

The corresponding ticket is [`KT-28031`](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28031).

Answer (score 1):

Add this on top of the declaration of the `parameters` property: `@Suppress("unused")`

You might need to re-compile the project to get IntelliJ to stop highlighting it as an unused property.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut though.